# What is difference between "as Long" and ".toLong()" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, operator-keyword

Here is an example:

```
    val a: Int = 6
    val b = a.toLong()
    val c = a as Long
```

what is difference between **.toLong()** and **as Long** keyword? And what is better way to use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a.toLong()` calls the [`toLong`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-long.html) method on `a`, so it will do whatever the `toLong` method does. This method is usually implemented with native code. For example, on the JVM, it can be implemented with the `i2l` JVM instruction.

The `as` operator on the other hand, does the following, according to the [language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#cast-expressions):

> This expression perform a runtime check whether the runtime type of `E` is a subtype of `T` and throws an exception otherwise.

So `as` only does a check at runtime. The "conversion" happens at compile time only, by means of the language mandating that the type of the expression `e as T` *must* be `T`.

As far as Kotlin's type system is concerned, `Int` is not a subtype of `Long`, so this check will always fail, and this expression will always throw an exception. Note that this is different from [Java's type system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1). where the primitive `int` *is* a subtype of the primitive `long`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `as` casts that object to that type. It only works when it actually is that type. You'll see that your code actually crashes there where you try to cast the `Int` to a `Long`. The `toLong()` function actually turns it into a `Long`.

Comment: "It only works when it actually is that type." Would you mind elaborating? What is the point of the 'as' keyword then? What situation would it be more useful than using a toLong()?

Comment: @user13267 it's when you want to cast it to a subtype of the variable. Let's say you have a class `Vehicle` and a subclass `Car`. Then you could cast a `Vehicle` to a `Car` if it actually is a `Car`